# AWS Lambda function times out but works locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web scraping python script that runs locally, returns the expected output, but when I deploy it to Lambda, it times out without returning anything. I'm pretty sure the code runs on lambda, because it gave me some selenium errors that I fixed, such as Element Not Interactable, so it definitely starts the code.
This is the lambda error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2024-03-12T18:37:30.864Z 85ac030a-4bf9-4a08-8ad8-ba93d1ff2477 Task timed out after 300.03 seconds"
}
```

:
My code is a big mess, I will try to rewrite it after it'll start working, but here it is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, ElementClickInterceptedException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


def handler(event=None, context=None):
    origin = "Madrid"
    destination = "Barcelona"
    fDate = 21
    lDate = 24
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    service = webdriver.ChromeService("/opt/chromedriver")

    options.binary_location = '/opt/chrome/chrome'
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--single-process")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
    options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={mkdtemp()}")
    options.add_argument(f"--data-path={mkdtemp()}")
    options.add_argument(f"--disk-cache-dir={mkdtemp()}")
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    url = 'https://www.renfe.com/es/en'

    driver.get(url)
    while True:
        try:
            cookie = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
            cookie.click()
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(2)
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass

    origin_station = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#origin")
    origin_station.send_keys(origin)
    driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[role='option']")[0].click()
    time.sleep(1)

    destination_station = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#destination")
    destination_station.send_keys(destination)
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/rf-header"
                                      "/rf-header-top/div/div[2]/rf-search/div/div[1]/rf-awesomplete[2]/div/"
                                      "div[1]/ul/li[1]").click()
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='first-input']").click()
    time.sleep(1)

    init_month = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='rf-daterange__month-label']")
    month = init_month.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span').text.strip()
    while month != "September":
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lightpick__next-action').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        init_month = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='rf-daterange__month-label']")
        month = init_month.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span').text.strip()

    first_days = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lightpick__day')[5:36]
    for day in first_days:
        if int(day.text) == fDate:
            day.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            break
    time.sleep(1)

    last_days = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lightpick__day')[5:36]
    for day in last_days:
        if int(day.text) == lDate:
            day.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            break

    accept_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='lightpick__apply-action-sub']")
    accept_btn.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")
    submit_btn.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/'
                                f'div[{1}]/div[1]/h5[1]')
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(15)
    for i in range(1, 15):
        hour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                   f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/'
                                   f'div[{i}]/div[1]/h5[1]').text
        if hour == '10:30 h':
            first_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]'
                                              f'/div[{i}]/div[3]/span').text
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                          f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]'
                                          f'/div[1]/div[{i}]/div[2]')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            time.sleep(3)
            button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                         "/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div")
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='select-more']").click()
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element(By.ID, 'cerrarConfirmacionMaletasAVLO').click()
            time.sleep(1)
            for j in range(1, 10):
                new_hour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/'
                                                         f'div[2]/div[{j}]/div[1]/h5[1]').text

                if new_hour == '06:35 h':
                    last_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                     f'/html/body/article/section/div/div[1]/div/'
                                                     f'div[3]/div[2]/div[{j}]/div[3]/span').text
                    break
            break
    first_price = (first_price.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[0].replace(",", "."))
    last_price = (last_price.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[0].replace(",", "."))
    first_price = float(first_price) * 2
    last_price = float(last_price) * 2
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": f"pret dus:{first_price}, pret intors:{last_price}",
    }
    return response
```

These are my Dockerfile and serverless.yml:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python@sha256:1d922f123370801843aad18d0911759c55402af4d0dddb601181df4ed42b2ce2 as build
RUN dnf install -y unzip && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip" "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.111/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip" && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chrome-linux64.zip" "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.111/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip" && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /opt/ && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /opt/

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python@sha256:1d922f123370801843aad18d0911759c55402af4d0dddb601181df4ed42b2ce2
RUN dnf install -y atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib \
    libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver \
    libXtst pango at-spi2-atk libXt xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
    xorg-x11-xauth dbus-glib dbus-glib-devel nss mesa-libgbm
RUN pip install selenium==4.18.1
COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux64 /opt/chrome
COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver-linux64 /opt/
COPY main.py ./
CMD [ "main.handler" ]
```

```
service: docker-selenium-lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'prod'}
  region: eu-north-1
  ecr:
    images:
      img:
        path: ./
        platform: linux/amd64

functions:
  demo:
    timeout: 60
    # If you experience any errors such as Chrome crashing or not being available you might need to increase the storage available to your Lambda Function. See #102
    memorySize: 2048
    image:
      name: img
```

I tried testing the function on AWS Lambda but it does not return anything

Comment: Have you tried increasing the resources allocated to your function or increasing the timeout? How long does it take to run locally?

Comment: @sytech I increased the timeout to 5 min and it says that it only uses 698MB of 2048MB available, still not working, it usually takes around 2-3 min locally

Comment: Did you add some debugging information so you can see what it is doing during this time, and what it was trying to do when it timed-out? You can `print` information and then view it in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: You're sure that it's not connected to your VPC?